# C++1y/C++14: Assignment to object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant expression?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr, c++14

Is the following C++14/C++1y program ill-formed according to the current draft?

```
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, size_t n>
struct literal_array
{
    T data[n];
};

template<typename T, size_t n, size_t m>
constexpr literal_array<T, n+m> operator+(literal_array<T, n> a,
                                          literal_array<T, m> b)
{
    literal_array<T, n+m> x;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        x.data[i] = a.data[i];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
        x.data[n+i] = b.data[i];

    return x;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr literal_array<int, 3> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    constexpr literal_array<int, 2> b = { 4, 5 };

    constexpr auto c = a + b;
}
```

Clang trunk (at time of writing) gives:

```
error: constexpr variable 'c' must be initialized by a constant expression
        constexpr auto c = a + b;
                       ^   ~~~~~
assignment to object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant expression
                x.data[i] = a.data[i];
                          ^
in call to 'operator+({{1, 2, 3}}, {{4, 5}})'
        constexpr auto c = a + b;
                           ^
```

What does it mean "assignment to object outside its lifetime"?  The lifetime of x and its subobjects encloses the function, so what is it on about?

Comment: If we simplify the problem by making the function non-template the error message makes more sense, see it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a13b63215578d063).

Comment: I filed a bug report and it received a reply, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The program is *ill-formed* because you are not initializing `x`, if you change the definition to:

```
literal_array<T, n+m> x = {{0}};
```

`clang` no longer complains and it compiles without error. Another solution would be to create *constexpr consrtuctors*.

We can find this in the [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf) section `7.1.5` *The constexpr specifier* paragraph *3* which says:

> The definition of a `constexpr` function shall satisfy the following
>   constraints:

and includes the following bullet:

> its *function-body* shall be `= delete`, `= default`, or a
>   *compound-statement* that does not contain

which contains this bullet (*emphasis mine*):

> a definition of a variable of non-literal type or of static or thread
>   storage duration **or for which no initialization is performed**.

and later on we have the following example:

```
constexpr int uninit() {
  int a; // error: variable is uninitialized
  return a;
}
```

The complaint about the lifetime of `x` does not seem founded in the [draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3797.pdf). The correct reason as far as I can tell should be something along the lines of `object is not initialized`.

The relevant quote from the draft standard on object lifetime would be section `3.8` *Object lifetime* paragraph *1* which says:

> The *lifetime* of an object is a runtime property of the object. An
>   object is said to have non-trivial initialization if it is of a class
>   or aggregate type and it or one of its members is initialized by a
>   constructor other than a trivial default constructor. [ *Note:*
>   initialization by a trivial copy/move constructor is non-trivial
>   initialization. — *end note* ] The lifetime of an object of type `T` begins
>   when:
>
> - storage with the proper alignment and size for type `T` is obtained, and
> - if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete.

Just in case I was missing something I also checked using [std::is_trivial](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial):

```
std::cout <<  std::boolalpha << std::is_trivial<literal_array<int, 3>>::value << std::endl ;
```

and the result as expected in `true`,.

**Update**

I filed a [bug report](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=18874) for this and the reply includes this statement:

> [...]The problem is that we don't yet implement the implied rule that such a function can't be invoked in a constant expression.

Comment: The bit about lifetime is a bit odd, but makes sense if you pretend that initialization is required to begin the lifetime of a `literal_array`, which being POD has relaxed lifetime rules.

Comment: If what you're looking for isn't in §3.8 [basic.life], you might be on a wild goosechase. I'd say that Clang is just wrong to say anything about lifetime in this case.

Comment: Your analysis is right -- Clang uses that diagnostic because the object is uninitialized. Uninitialized objects aren't supposed to be possible inside `constexpr` functions, so we don't have an 'uninitialized' diagnostic. The problem is that we shouldn't allow the call to `operator+` at all because it doesn't initialize `x`. (See also the longer explanation I left on your clang bug report.)

Comment: @RichardSmith ok, so although [N3652 is implemented](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) there are some quirks. I appreciate the explanation.