# Why isn't the compiler evaluating a constexpr function during compilation when every information is given?

Tags: c++, c++14, constexpr

This

```
int main()
{
  std::cout << range(1, 11).reverse().sort().sum() << std::endl;
}
```

is everything in `main`, and as the code says, it creates a list from 1 to 10 inclusive, reverses it, un-reverses it by sorting, and calculates the sum. The output should thus be 55.

The code is rather an experiment, (ab)using the relaxed requirements of `constexpr` in C++14. I did my best to create a compile-time list class, but really couldn't go far enough. The class is incomplete, but it still can imitate a lot of functional style programming.

As far as I understand, the requirements of `constexpr` are there to let the compiler evaluate things in compile-time. So I thought the compiler can simply replace everything with a constant 55 for my code, but it didn't. The code really has everything it needs to get the result in compile-time. What am I missing?

From the comments, I tried to check the problem by using the result in `static_assert`. clang and gcc both gives me an error, but I failed to understand either, and the latter seems to be broken...

**clang**

```
a.cpp:142:17: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
  static_assert(range(1, 11).reverse().sort().sum() == 55, "");
                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
a.cpp:60:23: note: assignment to object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant
      expression
  l.array[l.length++] = t;
                      ^
a.cpp:134:9: note: in call to '&l->add(1)'
    l = l.add(a);
        ^
a.cpp:142:17: note: in call to 'range(1, 11, 1)'
  static_assert(range(1, 11).reverse().sort().sum() == 55, "");
                ^
1 error generated.
```

**gcc**

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':

main.cpp:142:3: error: non-constant condition for static assertion

   static_assert(range(1, 11).reverse().sort().sum() == 55, "");

   ^

main.cpp:142:38: error: 'constexpr List<T> List<T>::reverse() const [with T = int]' called in a constant expression

   static_assert(range(1, 11).reverse().sort().sum() == 55, "");

                                      ^

main.cpp:74:19: note: 'constexpr List<T> List<T>::reverse() const [with T = int]' is not usable as a constexpr function because:

 constexpr List<T> List<T>::reverse() const

                   ^

main.cpp:74:19: sorry, unimplemented: unexpected AST of kind result_decl

main.cpp:74: confused by earlier errors, bailing out
```

---

**full code**

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <algorithm>
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename T>
class List
{
  template<typename T2>
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const List<T2> &);
public:
  constexpr List();
  constexpr List(std::initializer_list<T>);
  constexpr T head() const;
  constexpr List<T> tail() const;
  constexpr List<T> add(T) const;
  constexpr List<T> merge(List<T>) const;
  constexpr List<T> reverse() const;
  template<typename Filter>
  constexpr List<T> filter(Filter) const;
  constexpr List<T> sort() const;
  constexpr T sum() const;
private:
  int length;
  T array[0x100];
};

template<typename T>
constexpr List<T>::List()
: length(0)
{
}

template<typename T>
constexpr List<T>::List(std::initializer_list<T> l)
: length {static_cast<int>(l.size())}
{
  std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), array);
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T List<T>::head() const
{
  return array[0];
}

template<typename T>
constexpr List<T> List<T>::tail() const
{
  List<T> l;
  l.length = length - 1;
  std::copy_n(array + 1, l.length, l.array);
  return l;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr List<T> List<T>::add(T t) const
{
  List<T> l {*this};
  l.array[l.length++] = t;
  return l;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr List<T> List<T>::merge(List<T> l) const
{
  std::copy_backward(l.array, l.array + l.length, l.array + l.length + length);
  std::copy_n(array, length, l.array);
  l.length += length;
  return l;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr List<T> List<T>::reverse() const
{
  List<T> l;
  l.length = length;
  std::reverse_copy(array, array + length, l.array);
  return l;
}

template<typename T>
template<typename Filter>
constexpr List<T> List<T>::filter(Filter f) const
{
  List<T> l;
  for (int i {0}; i < length; ++i)
  {
    if (f(array[i]))
    {
      l = l.add(array[i]);
    }
  }
  return l;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr List<T> List<T>::sort() const
{
  if (length == 0)
  {
    return *this;
  }
  return tail().filter([&](T t) {return t < head();}).sort().add(head())
  .merge(tail().filter([&](T t) {return t >= head();}).sort());
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T List<T>::sum() const
{
  if (length == 0)
  {
    return T {};
  }
  return head() + tail().sum();
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const List<T> &l)
{
  os << '{';
  for (int i {0}; i < l.length - 1; ++i)
  {
    os << l.array[i] << ", ";
  }
  return os << l.array[l.length - 1] << '}';
}

inline constexpr List<int> range(int a, int b, int c = 1)
{
  List<int> l;
  while (a < b)
  {
    l = l.add(a);
    a += c;
  }
  return l;
}

int main()
{
  static_assert(range(1, 11).reverse().sort().sum(), "");
  std::cout << range(1, 11).reverse().sort().sum() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: It's better to check it like: `static_assert(range(1, 11).reverse().sort().sum() == 55, "");` and that compiler will tell you, which part cannot be used in constant expression.

Comment: @ForEveR I now get an error message: `note: assignment to object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant expression l.array[l.length++] = t;`, could you help me a bit what it means?

Comment: c++ only says that the expression must be able to evaluate at compile time. This did not mean that it is done during compile time. Exactly that is the reason why I use MTP for that. Did you try to make the result a value for a compile time constant, e.g. for a template int parameter constant?

Comment: gcc gives me a funny error message `main.cpp:74:19: note: 'constexpr List<T> List<T>::reverse() const [with T = int]' is not usable as a constexpr function because: sorry, unimplemented: unexpected AST of kind result_decl confused by earlier errors, bailing out`...

Comment: Related to [C++1y/C++14: Assignment to object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21806154/1708801)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The initial error is that `array` is not initialized in your constructor. You can fix this by initializing it:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr List<T>::List()
: length(0)
, array{}
{
}
```

After that, you will run into the problem that the `<algorithm>` functions you use are not `constexpr`; you can fix this by copying the example definitions from the standard into your implementation and marking your copies `constexpr`:

```
template<class BidirIt, class OutputIt>
constexpr OutputIt reverse_copy(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, OutputIt d_first)
{
    while (first != last) {
        *(d_first++) = *(--last);
    }
    return d_first;
}

// etcetera
```

Finally, you're using lambdas as filter predicates (in `sort`); lambdas are illegal in a constant-expression. The fix here is to expand the lambdas by hand into function objects:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr List<T> List<T>::sort() const
{
  if (length == 0)
  {
    return *this;
  }
  T pivot = head();
  struct Lt { T pivot; constexpr bool operator()(T t) const { return t < pivot; } };
  struct Ge { T pivot; constexpr bool operator()(T t) const { return t >= pivot; } };
  return tail().filter(Lt{pivot}).sort().add(pivot)
    .merge(tail().filter(Ge{pivot}).sort());
}
```

With these changes your code will compile under clang 3.7, though not gcc 5.2.0.

---

gcc 5.2.0 has two bugs:

First, it doesn't like the combined decrement-indirection `*(--last)` in `reverse_copy`; this is easily fixed:

```
template<class BidirIt, class OutputIt>
constexpr OutputIt reverse_copy(BidirIt first, BidirIt last, OutputIt d_first)
{
    while (first != last) {
        --last;
        *(d_first++) = *last;
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Second, it doesn't like comparing pointers into `array`; however, it can be satisfied by changing `array + length` to `&array[length]`.

[Live example](http://goo.gl/qGLMMd) with these changes (works with clang 3.7 and gcc 5.2.0).

Comment: I was actually trying the same thing as yours, although stuck at the lambda part :/

Comment: Interesting, it looks like you made it work partly by replacing most mutations with temporary objects and assignment

Answer (score 5):

> I did my best to create a compile-time list class

That's nothing like a compile-time list, though - the values are stored in an array, and the length is mutated during insertion. A compile-time list would be a variadic template of non-type parameters, or something like the [Boost.MPL Integral Sequence Wrapper](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/integral-sequence-wrapper.html), or a Loki-style recursive list of non-type parameters.

What you tried - and ecatmur succeeded - writing, is a runtime list which can, sometimes, be constexpr'd away.

Specifically in your code, the `List` members are *not constant*; the constexpr-runtime-list solution was to avoid mutating members and jump through some other constexpr hoops, whereas the compile-time list solution is to make the length (and values) properties of the *type*.

---

To get you started, here's a cheesy and incomplete variadic list, and some of the algorithms you want:

```
template <int... Values> struct VList {};

template <int X, typename Xs> struct cat;
template <int X, int... Xs> struct cat<X, VList<Xs...>> {
    using result = VList<X, Xs...>;
};
template <typename Xs, int X> struct rcat;
template <int... Xs, int X> struct rcat<VList<Xs...>, X> {
    using result = VList<Xs..., X>;
};
template <typename L> struct reverse;
template <int X> struct reverse<VList<X>> { using result = VList<X>; };
template <int X, int Y> struct reverse<VList<X, Y>> { using result = VList<Y, X>; };
template <int X, int... Xs> struct reverse<VList<X, Xs...>> {
    using result = typename rcat<typename reverse<VList<Xs...>>::result, X>::result;
};
template <int From, int To> struct range;
template <int End> struct range <End,End> { using result = VList<End>; };
template <int From, int To> struct range {
    using result = typename cat<From, typename range<From+1,To>::result>::result;
};

int main()
{
  typename range<1,11>::result l;
  typename reverse<decltype(l)>::result r;
  return sizeof(l) + sizeof(r);
}
```

note that:

- `VList` is just a type wrapper and its contents don't matter. We could equally use `std::tuple<std::integral_constant<int, ...>...>`
- `range` should assert that `From<=To`, could allow strides, etc.
- we don't really need the middle `reverse` specialization
- `cat` should really be called `push_front` or something, and `rcat`, `push_back`. I started the sketch with `car` for the former, and decided that might be wilfully obscure in the context. Besides, that would have made more sense for the recursive version.
- the `X,Xs...` notation is based on Haskell's `x:xs` convention. Functional languages are often a good place to look for inspiration when you're converting data types and algorithms to compile-time operation.

Comment: If it is like so, than what are all the requirements of `constexpr` for?

Comment: _If_ the compiler can determine all the relevant values at compile time, _then_ it may elide the runtime computation. In your case it never can, because you wrote runtime variables which have to be mutated at runtime. There's no requirement the compiler figure out for you that constexpr-ness will never be achievable with your code.

Comment: If you try to declare a `constexpr` variable of your type then the compiler will tell you it can't be evaluated at compile time.

Comment: @Useless Your claim seems to be wrong, see the selected answer. With a little tweak there appears to be no problem in full compile-time evaluation.

Comment: @xiver77 - interesting, thanks! That's more than I'd expected the compiler to handle.

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by: [C++1y/C++14: Assignment to object outside its lifetime is not allowed in a constant expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21806154/c1y-c14-assignment-to-object-outside-its-lifetime-is-not-allowed-in-a-const)

The private members of your `List` class are not initialized at compile time, so they can only live at run time, not at compile time. If you make the change to have them read:

```
int length = 0;
T array[0x100] = {0};
```

you get one step further to a new compile error ;). Another way is to initialize `array` in your `constexpr` constructor properly too:

```
template<typename T>
constexpr List<T>::List()
  : length(0),
    array({0})
{
}
```

Though as Useless mentioned, it may be difficult/impossible to get what you want done at all.